# How to save theme colors programmatically in powerpoint?

Tags: c#, .net, powerpoint

My Add-In provides a Color Picker for the user to select some colors. I want to know how to save these selected colors as a theme in PowerPoint (which i can load later).

Comment: It is a large project. I have panels in a custom task pane. I need to save the BackColor of the Panels for later use (as a palette for the user). I just need some direction to save and load elegantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started with modifying/creating/saving/loading themes.

```
Sub FiddleTheThemeColors()

    Dim x As Long
    ' Each slide can have its own color theme;
    ' We'll work with the theme for slide 1
    With ActivePresentation.Slides(1)

        ' First display its rgb values
        ' For your purposes, you'd want to save these somehow
        For x = 1 To .ThemeColorScheme.Count
            Debug.Print .ThemeColorScheme(x).RGB
        Next

        ' Then change the theme
        ' In your case, to whatever values you've saved
        ' But for demonstration purposes, a series of shades of gray
        For x = 1 To .ThemeColorScheme.Count
            .ThemeColorScheme(x).RGB = RGB(x * 20, x * 20, x * 20)
        Next

        ' The .ThemeColorScheme object has .Save and .Load methods
        ' that might work for you ... this will save the theme:
        .ThemeColorScheme.Save "C:\Temp\GrayTheme.thmx"

        ' see below for an example of loading the saved theme

    End With

End Sub

Sub LoadColorScheme()

    With ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
        .ThemeColorScheme.Load "C:\Temp\GrayTheme.thmx"
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a C# solution for the same?

Comment: No doubt there is.  It's all a matter of automating PowerPoint.  The language you choose is up to you.  You've chosen one I don't speak, so can't help translate.

Comment: Great ... you might want to pay it forward by posting your code here.